# PyTest-qt handle QFileDialog automatically

Tags: python, pytest, pyside6, pytest-qt

I have a PySide6 application, for which I want to test that when cancelling the file dialog, nothing changes. Here is part of the function where the dialog is called:

```
def change_folder(self, side: int):
        self.dialog = QFileDialog(self)
        new_folder_name = (
            self.dialog.getExistingDirectory(
                self, caption="Select a folder"
            )
        )
...
```

And here part of the test for it.

```
@pytest.fixture
def main_window(qtbot):
    qApp = QApplication.instance()
    if qApp is None:
        app = QApplication([""])
    else:
        app = qApp
    window = MainWindow()
    qtbot.addWidget(window)
    window.show()
    return window

def test_change_folder(main_window, qtbot):
    def handle_dialog():
        dialog = main_window.dialog
        # alternative: dialog = QApplication.activeWindow()
        qtbot.addWidget(dialog)
        dialog.reject()
        # alternative: qtbot.mouseClick(dialog.buton(QFileDialog.Cancel), Qt.LeftButton, delay=1)

    QTimer.singleShot(500, handle_dialog)
    qtbot.mouseClick(main_window.change_folder_left_button, Qt.LeftButton, delay=1)
    assert not main_window.dialog.isVisible()
    ...
```

I followed the instructions from [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-qt/issues/256), but i cant make it work, I always have to click the cancel button myself, if not  the dialog just stays open. Why could that be?

Comment: [`getExistingDirectory()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory) is a **static** function: it creates a separate QFileDialog instance with its own event loop, and it has absolutely no relation with that `self.dialog` instance you created, which is completely useless. Either construct a full QFileDialog instance, or implement the test in order to wait for a new dialog to appear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For other people with this problem, getting the dialog with "QApplication.activeModalWidget()" worked.